# Azure Function : Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have an Console Application with Target Framework .NET Framework v4.6.1 that I published it to Azure Functions. That application works without any error. There is no problem with that.

One of it's Nuget packages needed to be updated. But that updated version needs at least .NET Framework v4.6.2. So I have updated my Console Application's Target Framework level to 4.6.2 and I debugged it in my local. No problem with that.

But now I can't run the application on Azure. It won't build and run the function.
What do I need to do on Azure end?

> 2022-09-08T13:07:22.403 [Error] D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\CreatePlanningAndUserOverviewYearly.exe : System.Management.Automation.RemoteExceptionat run.ps1: line 1+ D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\CreatePlanningAndUserOverviewYearly.exe+ ________________________________________________________________+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
> 2022-09-08T13:07:22.416 [Error] D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\CreatePlanningAndUserOverviewYearly.exe : Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)at UES.CRM.Backend.CreatePlanningAndUserOverviewYearly.Main(String[] args)at run.ps1: line 1+ D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\CreatePlanningAndUserOverviewYearly.exe+ ________________________________________________________________+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], RemoteException+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandErrorMessage
> 2022-09-08T13:07:22.463 [Error] Exception while executing function: Functions.CreatePlanningAndUserOverviewYearly. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: PowerShell script error. .
> 2022-09-08T13:07:22.478 [Error] Function completed (Failure, Id=fb0c79e2-d4bc-4992-b1ec-292f8b77db62, Duration=1494ms)

Comment: What version Azure Functions are you using? Are you still able to deploy and run the old function? Are you sure it runs on 4.6.1 as this is not supported anymore by Azure Functions.

Comment: it says custom(~1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used Kudu to go bin folder. Deleted the old dlls there and uploaded the new ones. It solved.